# tcpdf in wordpress output crazy code

Tags: wordpress, tcpdf

i would like to implement the tcpdf in my wordpress project. I tried to call below example tcpdf file (it's an example from tcpdf), unfortunately its output are crazy code as below,
%PDF-1.7 %���� 8 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20180829011846+00'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox.....

I have no idea what's the problem of this, many many thanks if any guidance to me, thank you very much.

```
<?php
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
ob_end_clean(); 

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 038');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 038', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$txt = 'Example of CID-0 CJK unembedded font.
To display extended text you must have CJK fonts installed for your PDF reader:';
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('cid0jp', '', 40);

$txt = 'こんにちは世界';
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_038.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: You say this is being called in WordPress.  In what context is this code being run? A page template? An AJAX action?

Comment: this is a locate_template file from the ajax action. thank you.

Comment: Might you be able to add the following to your script: `print_r(ob_list_handlers());` and append the result to your question? Right before `ob_end_clean();` should work. (This'll further break your script, so be sure to remove it after.) This'll list any output buffering handlers.  What I suspect is happening is that the output is being buffered and a later call - possibly inside a handler- changes the content-type header to `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

In the pdf output method, try 'F' as the second argument instead of 'I'.

```
$pdf->Output('example_038.pdf', 'F');
```